# Persisting state on a master page's hierarchical list

Tags: asp.net

I'm writing an ASP.Net application (no AJAX, but maybe) and there's a requirement to have a list of companies graded under a traffic light system. I intend to have these in a collapsible hierarchical list on the Master page, e.g. Red expands to show companies, and then companies can be further expanded.

Question is, how can I keep the expanded list in the same place, with the same content visible, between page loads?

I'm only looking for pointers, not spoonfeeding ;-)

Mike K.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your problem?  If you include this on the master page, why would it not show up in the same place from page to page?  Are you wanting to preserve the collapsed state of the list?  Are you averse to using session state?  If so, why?

Comment: Hello Joel, I do want this on the master page so it will appear on every page, sorry I didn't make that clear. I do want to preserve the collapsed state of the list / control(s), and have no problem using session state to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested repeaters or datalists.  Pay attention to selected indexes and bind your child repeater or datalist in the itemdatabound event.

Definately not being spoon fed here.  That's throwing dinner on the table with no plates or cutlery.